# How to automatically update field creator orders

Tags: field-calculator, labeling, fields-attributes, autofields

I'm new to QGIS and want to visualize two attributes of a Layer:

- a) name (name of a hilltop)
- b) fotoid (referring to a photo of that hill)

Therefore I created a new field: "combined" with the field calculator and following content:

```
concat( name, fotoid)
```

However I would like the content of "combined" to be updated when I change the attributes of fotoid.

Is there a version of the plugin Autofields available for QGIS 3.28.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

###### Solution 1: Dynamic label (expression based)

Simply introduce the expression to the label's Value field to make the label dynamic, based on the content of the fields (see screenshot).

[image]

###### Solution 2: Virtual Field

Create the field `combined` as a [virtual field](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field): this will update dynamically and adapt to changing content in the fields `name` and `fotoid`.